# Why is my function not behaving asynchronously (asyncio to_thread)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Learning from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8tnmEdeOU0), I'm trying to make my codes run faster.
I have a synchronous get function (here represented by `mySynchronousFunction`) that I want to evaluate over several values in a List.
I am coding all this in a jupyter notebook.

Here is a MWE:

```py
# Cell one
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import sleep

# cell two
def mySynchronousFunction():
    sleep(4)
    return(True)

async def turningMyFunctionAsync(string):
    print(f"starting job for {string}")
    returnVal = await asyncio.to_thread(mySynchronousFunction)
    print(f"end of job for {string}")
    return(returnVal)

# Cell tree
myList = [{'val':'val1'},{'val':'val2'},{'val':'val3'},{'val':'val4'},{'val':'val5'}]
async def mainAsyncFunction():
    for val in myList:
        val['result'] = await asyncio.create_task(turningMyFunctionAsync(val['val']))

# Cell four
await mainAsyncFunction()

# Prints:
# starting job for val1
# end of job for val1
# starting job for val2
# end of job for val2
# starting job for val3
# end of job for val3
# starting job for val4
# end of job for val4
# starting job for val5
# end of job for val5
```

I was expecting cell four to print all the "starting job for val1" first (i.e. launching all the processes at ones) considering the huge sleep time. But everything just run synchronously.
What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use asyncio.sleep().  The regular sleep function is blocking.

Comment: That's not the issue. The `mySynchronousFunction` is a synchronous function that they want to turn into an asynchronous one using `asyncio.to_thread`. This is a common problem where you may not have control over what `mySynchronousFunction` does and can't directly turn it into a coroutine, which is where `asyncio.to_thread` comes into play. In this case, the actual issue is the `for` loop, which is making the task creation and awaiting synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `for` loop inside `mainAsyncFunction`. The `for` loop is making your tasks synchronous because inside each iteration, you are awaiting the end of the task. So in each iteration, you create the task and then await it, which means that you start `mySynchronousFunction` in another thread and then get its value, all before continuing to the next iteration.

Also, note that your code actually doesn't run as is. You cannot call `await` outside of a coroutine. The only place this is allowed, I believe, is inside a Python REPL, which is done as a special case to make things easier to test I suppose.

There are several ways to solve this. There is `async for` which could potentially be used, but to be honest, I don't know how to use it. There are also [`TaskGroups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups). In this case, I created a solution that keeps it simple. We can simply build up a list of coroutines. Then, `asyncio.gather` is called on that list, which turns every coroutine into a task if it isn't already a task. Note the difference between running a coroutine directly and a task is that tasks execute concurrently. `asyncio.gather` is just one way to launch coroutines as concurrent tasks. Also note that `asyncio.gather` does not take a list. So one needs to use the `*coroutines` to pass the list as comma-separated arguments. In other words, `asyncio.gather(coro1, coro2, coro3)` is equivalent to `asyncio.gather(*coros)` for `coros = [coro1, coro2, coro3]`. Lastly, `asyncio.gather` returns a list of the task results in the order that they were passed into `asyncio.gather`.

```py
async def mainAsyncFunction():
    coroutines = [turningMyFunctionAsync(val["val"]) for val in myList]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
    print(f"Results: {results}")
    return results

asyncio.run(mainAsyncFunction())
```

This prints out:

```
starting job for val1
starting job for val2
starting job for val3
starting job for val4
starting job for val5
end of job for val1
end of job for val2
end of job for val3
end of job for val4
end of job for val5
Results: [True, True, True, True, True]
```

My final comment is that `asyncio` does not necessarily make your code faster. It makes it concurrent. In cases where you are using pure coroutines and tasks and are not deferring to threads, it is possible that `asyncio` is faster because it is single threaded and thus avoids the overhead of switching threads. However, in your case, you are deferring to a thread. By default `asyncio.to_thread` uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which I believe defaults to creating a thread pool that has as many threads as cores, so it does save some overhead of creating threads, but it still switches between them.

Comment: Thanks I understand better now. I use `await` instead of  `asyncio.run(mainAsyncFunction())` because I'm working in a Jupyter notebook which each cell seem to interfere with ayncio. It prompts the error: "RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"

Comment: Oh, I see. I believe I read somewhere that the Python REPL allows `await` directly in it, which is probably explaining why that works in a Jupyter notebook also. The REPL and notebook implementations must be starting up an event loop themselves.